# Functions representable as a sum of a continuous function and a periodic function, and the axiom of choice.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cardinals, periodic-functions

Let $A$ be the set of continuous functions from the reals to the reals, let $P$ be the set of periodic functions from the reals to the reals, and $F$ be the set of all functions from the reals to the reals. Let $S$ the set of functions which are expressible as the sum of an element from $A$ and an element from $P$. Note that $A$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but $P$ has the same cardinality as $2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$ which is the cardinality of $F$.  So there is no cardinality based argument that there are elements in $F$ which are not in $S$.

However, it seems like there should be elements in $F$ which are not in $S$, and my guess is that there should be some construction possibly using a Hamel basis.

In that context I  have three questions:

1. Can we show there is an element of $F/S$?
2. Can we prove 1 without assuming the Axiom of Choice?
3. Do the answers for 1 and 2 change if in $A$ we allow instead of just continuous functions, functions which are continuous except at countably many points?

Comment: if I understand correctly, for any element $f \in S$, we can find a positive number $T>0$ such that $ g(x)= f(x+T)-f(x)$ is a continuous function. Right? So the strict inclusion is clear.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Yes, that's an equivalent formulation. So how do you construct then  an f(x) which obviously does not have that property?

Comment: I don't know. Some step functions with varying length? I think the construction is not that hard. It is now more about whether you can construct something nice.Like f(x)= [x^2], I think it'll do the work.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Ah, yes, I think that example works. Thank you. I was making this much more difficult than it needed to be.

Comment: We are all like that sometimes. All the best.